# Why my Google Sheet QUERY getting error when selecting date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I want to query data between two dates. Here is my query:

```
=query(Profile;"select * where B >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("27/02/2018"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and B <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("01/03/2018"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"";1)
```

[image]

and here is the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AvyMhjPMDeX6lszrrF4dqXssZSzYPuZdcbsQ66jzQOg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What does it have anything to do with sql server?

Comment: It has nothing to do, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the correct syntax:

```
=QUERY(Profile; 
 "where B >= date '"&TEXT(C3; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and B <= date '"&TEXT(C4; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"; 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but can you make the date format into dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy?

Comment: sure: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(QUERY(Profile; 
 "where B >= date '"&TEXT(C3; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and B <= date '"&TEXT(C4; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"; 1); "dd-mm-yyyy"))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnJtQ.png

Comment: Thanks again.  I mean can you make the cell B in dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

It looks that a `'` is missing on `&""`. It should be `&"'"`

The final formula is

`=query(Profile;"select * where B >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("27/02/2018"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and B <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("01/03/2018"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'";1)`

Comment: Tried your solution, but still generates error message

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of the date string you are passing to mm/dd/yyyy instead of the current dd/mm/yyyy and it should work.

e.g. from @Ruben example above:

```
=query(Profile;"select * where B >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("02/27/2018"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and B <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("03/01/2018"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'";1)
```

It seems like this is a backwards step from the formula you asked about yesterday, which deals with date formatting itself rather than manually having to pass a date as a string: